# Как установить дату по умолчанию в datepicker из переменной?

Tags: jquery

Мне надо как-то модифицировать данный код, чтобы в defaulDay подставлялось значение из переменной, которое получается из содержимого тэга span.

```
<div style="height:0px; overflow:hidden">
    <input class="datepicker-input" type="date"/>
</div>
<span class="edit date" contenteditable="true"><Date?></span>

$('.datepicker-input').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    defaultDate:  defaultDay
    onClose(dateText, inst) {
        $(this).parent().next('.date').text([
            inst.selectedDay,
            inst.selectedMonth + 1,
            inst.selectedYear
        ].join('-'));
    }
});

$('.date').click(function() {
    defaultDay = $(this).text();
    $( this ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        defaultDate:  defaultDay
    });
    $(this).prev('div').find('.datepicker-input').focus();
});
```

У меня получилось вывести правильный календарь, но вот только он становится не кликабельным =(

Answer (score 0):

Определил обработчик для показа календаря на "двойной клик", иначе не вижу смысла делать `span contenteditable="true"`:

```js
$('.datepicker-input').datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
  defaultDate: $('.date').text(),
  onClose(dateText, inst) {
    $(this).parent().next('.date').text([
      inst.selectedDay,
      inst.selectedMonth + 1,
      inst.selectedYear
    ].join('-'));
  }
});

$('.date').on('dblclick', function() {
  defaultDay = $(this).text();
  $('.datepicker-input').datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', $('.date').text());
  $(this).prev('div').find('.datepicker-input').focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div style="height:0px; overflow:hidden">
  <input class="datepicker-input" type="date" />
</div>
<span class="edit date" contenteditable="true">19-11-2018</span>
```